# Re-use parts of a linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We have a program that uses Linq-To-Sql and does a lot of similar queries on our tables.  In particular, we have a timestamp column, and we pull the most recent timestamp to see if the table has changed since our last query.

```
System.Data.Linq.Binary ts;
ts = context.Documents
    .Select(r => r.m_Timestamp)
    .OrderByDescending(r => r)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

We repeat this query often on different tables that's relevant for the current form/query whatever.  What I would like to do is create a "function" or something that can repeat the last 3 lines of this query (and ideally would work on every table).  Here's what I would like to write:

```
System.Data.Linq.Binary ts;
ts = context.Documents
    .GetMostRecentTimestamp();
```

But I have no idea how to create this "GetMostRecentTimestamp".  Also, these queries are never this simple.  They usually filter by the Customer, or by the current order, so a more valid query might be

```
ts = context.Documents
    .Where(r => r.CustomerID == ThisCustomerID)
    .GetMostRecentTiemstamp();
```

Any help?  Thanks!

---

#### Update [Solution]

I selected Bala R's answer, here's the code updated so it compiles:

```
public static System.Data.Linq.Binary GetMostRecentTimestamp(this IQueryable<Data.Document> docs)
{
    return docs
        .Select(r => r.m_Timestamp)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The only drawback to this solution is that I will have to write this function for each table.   I would have loved Tejs's answer, if it actually worked, but I'm not re-designing my database for it.  Plus DateTime is a not a good way to do timestamps.

---

#### Update #2 (Not so fast)

While I can do a query such as Documents.Where( ... ).GetMostRecentTimestamp(), this solution fails if I try to do an association based query such as MyCustomer.Orders.GetMostRecentTimestamp(), or MyCustomer.Orders.AsQueryable().GetMostRecentTimestamp();

Comment: Regarding Update#2, how does it fail?

Comment: Regarding "DateTime is a not a good way to do timestamps.", you might be crazy.

Comment: So if someone comes in and accidently updates the servers datetime to say 2012, for just a single update, then all future queries will find that DateTime using the .Max() query.  Then all my checks to see if there's newer data will say "nope, I have the latest row".  I guess you could just cross your fingers and hope no one bumps the DateTime of the server.

Comment: Update #2 Fails because its a compiler error/invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an extension like this

```
public static DateTime GetMostRecentTimestamp (this IQueryable<Document> docs)
{
    return docs.Select(r => r.m_Timestamp)
               .OrderByDescending(r => r)
               .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I am presuming OP should extend `IQueryable<Document>` (it is Linq to Sql if I got it right).  And `FirstOrDefault` should return a single `Document`.

Comment: Thanks!  This actually complies and works.  I'll just have to write it for every table.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually pretty easy to do. You simply need to define an interface on the entities you wish to provide this for:

```
public class MyEntity : ITimestamp
```

Then, your extenstion method:

```
public static DateTime GetMostRecentTimestamp<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable)
    where T : ITimestamp
{
     return queryable.Select(x => x.m_Timestamp)
            .OrderByDescending(r => r)
            .FirstOrDefault()
}
```

This is then useful on any entity that matches the interface:

```
context.Documents.GetMostRecentTimestamp()
context.SomeOtherEntity.GetMostRecentTimestamp()
```

Comment: One small caveat: you must ensure that the timestamp property has exactly the same name in all implementations of the ITimestamp interface. Otherwise linq2sql won't be able to translate the query and you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: I actually already have the ITimestamp interface, but that gives me a compiler error: Error 'T' does not contain a definition for 'm_Timestamp' and no extension method 'm_Timestamp' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found.

Comment: ITimestamp must have m_Timestamp property, that all objects, that implement this interface must implement.

Comment: So I define in the interface: 
        `System.Data.Linq.Binary p_Timestamp { get; }`
 but I get 
`NotSupportedException: The member 'ITimestamp.p_Timestamp' has no supported translation to SQL.`  Here's the current ver. of the function:
        `public static System.Data.Linq.Binary GetMostRecentTimestamp<T>(this IQueryable<T> docs)
            where T : Interfaces.ITimestamp
        {
            return docs
                       .OrderByDescending(r => r.p_Timestamp)
                       .Select(r => r.p_Timestamp)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
        }`

Comment: You would have `public DateTime p_Timestamp { get; set; }` in your interface. Or however your entity is to be used.

Comment: @Tejs: The timestamp is readonly, but I have that defined in the interface. `System.Data.Linq.Binary p_Timestamp { get;}`   Maybe this is an error only with the System.Data.Linq.Binary data type (I'm not using DateTime!)

Comment: I'd say stop using the Binary data type then, if it's not supported by Linq2Sql =D

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

```
DateTime timeStamp1 = dataContext.Customers.Max(c => c.TimeStamp);
DateTime timeStamp2 = dataContext.Orders.Max(c => c.TimeStamp);
DateTime timeStamp3 = dataContext.Details.Max(c => c.TimeStamp);
```

Comment: .Max() does not work with System.Linq.Data.Binary.  I am not using DateTime objects as a database timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

I created a pair of extension methods that could help you out: ObjectWithMin and ObjectWithMax:

```
public static T ObjectWithMax<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, TResult> projection)
        where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
    {
        if (elements == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elements", "Sequence is null.");
        if (!elements.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequence contains no elements.");

        var seed = elements.Select(t => new {Object = t, Projection = projection(t)}).First();

        return elements.Aggregate(seed,
                                  (s, x) =>
                                  projection(x).CompareTo(s.Projection) >= 0
                                      ? new {Object = x, Projection = projection(x)}
                                      : s
            ).Object;
    }

public static T ObjectWithMin<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Func<T, TResult> projection)
        where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
    {
        if (elements == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elements", "Sequence is null.");
        if (!elements.Any()) throw new ArgumentException("Sequence contains no elements.");

        var seed = elements.Select(t => new {Object = t, Projection = projection(t)}).First();

        return elements.Aggregate(seed,
                                  (s, x) =>
                                  projection(x).CompareTo(s.Projection) < 0
                                      ? new {Object = x, Projection = projection(x)}
                                      : s
            ).Object;
    }
```

These two are more efficient than OrderBy().FirstOrDefault() when used on in-memory collections; however they're unparseable by IQueryable providers. You'd use them something like this:

```
ts = context.Documents
    .Where(r => r.CustomerID == ThisCustomerID)
    .ObjectWithMax(r=>r.m_Timestamp);
```

`ts` is now the object having the most recent timestamp, so you don't need a second query to get it.

Comment: I believe OP is talking about database access, meaning that these aggregate delegates will be too complex to be translated into sql.